# How does a DBMS use File I/O to read a database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, file-io

I want to learn more about databases and how they work at a low level so I can try to write a really, really basic one for learning purposes. I was wondering if databases like MySQL and SQL Server use traditional File I/O to read the database files, or if there is a more advanced mechanism for reading disk sectors or specific blocks?

By traditional File I/O I mean using something like

```
FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode)
```

in C.

I know that InnoDB uses 16kb pages in the database to store metadata and records. I don't know if they just precalculate how many pages they may need to skip in order to find a value based on an index and then seek that page in the file or if they have some more advanced access control.

Comment: Learn about BTrees -- Wikipedia is a good start.  Yes, MySQL uses ordinary I/O.  For the 16KB blocks there is a seek then a read or write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a research paper [here](http://db.cs.berkeley.edu/papers/fntdb07-architecture.pdf) by Joseph M. Hellerstein, Michael Stonebraker
and James Hamilton that explains storage management starting on page 210. It talks about how a DBMS can use the file system or raw disk access where it writes to logical, sequential blocks.

A DBMS can use either/or or even both types of disk access to manage the databases. You get slightly better performance from raw disk access but raw access comes with some disadvantages, like dedicating full partitions to a database. A large file can be used and often enough the file offset is close to the physical location on disk, so large files offer minimal degradation in I/O performance in best-case scenarios.

A [virtual disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_disk) is another option for simulating raw disk access, and according to the research paper, is becoming the norm.